Beyond Compare grammar. Color only regex matching groups, not whole match
I want to add syntax highlight for AL language to Beyond Compare using grammar.
For example I have following line
EventSubscriberInstance = Manual;

AL have a lot of this properties and I don't want to put them all to grammar. I want to match them with regex like this
<PropertyName> = <PropertyValue>;

But I want to match and color only <PropertyName>. For this I added following pattern
^\s+(\w+)\s=\s(\w+);$

It matches the whole string and colors it.
How do I match the whole string by pattern, but color only part of it?
I tried to add capture groups. My expectation was that only groups would be colored.
Also tried to add positive lookahead like this.
^\s+(\w+)(?=\s=\s(\w+);$)

It matches only PropertyName, but BC5 won't accept this pattern with error "Invalid regular expression:Character expected at position 11". Seems like it can't handle lookaheads.
Coloring I want to acheive: property name, property, and opertors (= and ;) value colored differentrly.


Sorry, this isn't possible in Beyond Compare. It doesn't provide a method to match the whole string by pattern, but color only part of it.
